# Verify if Kafka queue is empty

Tags: apache-kafka

We have pushed messages onto kafka queues 2 days back and the retention is set to 2 days so its going to expire today . Is there any way of knowing exactly when kafka queues are empty/not having any data in them?

I am a beginner in Hadoop system so I don't know if there is any command to find this/easy way to verify the empty queues

Answer (score 1):

You can write a own little tool using `KafkaConsumer` laveraging `seekToEnd()`, `seekToBeginning()`, and `position()` to get min and max offsets per partition. If both match for all partitions, the topic is empty.

Comment: Will it not show **only** partition and replica set distribution along with if all the replicas are in sync or not ? `kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1`. I am not sure about `0.9` above. Just curious.

Comment: Oh sorry. I thought it does report max and min offset. Updated my answer.